# Set a reminder in Calendar after user selects date/time from Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-calendar

I have an app that has a 'Reminder' button which will prompt user to select the date/time for when he wants that reminder. The date/time, along with some text that will be added within the app, should automatically create a calendar event without the user being directed to the Calendar app. I am able to get the date/time input from user, but don't know how to go from there.

Just to be sure, the user only has to select the date and time, rest must be done programmatically. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write to calendar android database ([CalendarContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract))

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider

For example if you want to add simple calendar event just use this code

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0;
long endMillis = 0;
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

More [examples](http://www.zoftino.com/how-to-read-and-write-calendar-data-in-android)